# Taylor Series Representation of $e^{1-\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Hello I was wondering how to simplify this Taylor Series

$$
e^{1-\cos(x)} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1-\cos(x))}{k!} ^k\
$$

to where I can write out the first couple of terms which are $ 1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{x^6}{720}$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by simplify? You could use: $1-cos(x) = sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$. But it would end up giving you the LHS again.

Comment: @tpb261 That should be $2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews My bad. Can I edit comments? I guess not.

Comment: @tpb261 You can within $5$ minutes of posting your original comment I believe

Comment: do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the full power series you could use [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version).

However, to get the first couple of terms, you just have to compose them as truncated polynomials as is done in [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#First_example).

Answer (score 2):

One way to see this is to note that $f(x)=e^{1-\cos x}$ is analytic and has a power series expansion, and that it is an even function. So $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$. Noting that
$f'(x)=\sin(x)f(x)$ we conclude that
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2(n+1) a_{n+1}x^{2n+1}
$$
Equating the coefficients of $x^{2n+1}$ and noting that $f(0)=1$, we conclude that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is defined by the recursion :
$$
a_0=1,\quad\hbox{and for $n\geq0$},\quad a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}a_{n-k}.
$$
For example this gives
$$f(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{x^6}{720}-\frac{43
   x^8}{40320}-\frac{127 x^{10}}{1814400}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{12}\right).$$